# I have code with Dynamically load using PHP code ,Here I need to set selected value for the option value

Tags: php

I have code with Dynamically load using PHP code ,Here I need to set selected value for the option value when  `($value1->item_id == $value1->item_id) ? selected ='selected'` but its not working

```
<table class="table" >
   <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th> <button type="button" id="add_new_row" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon 
         glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php
        $dy_code="";
        foreach ($edit_item_data as $key => $value){
        $dy_code=$dy_code."<select class='select2_single form-control chosen-select item_id item_select'`enter code here`
          tabindex='-1' name='item_data[]'>";$dy_code=$dy_code."<option value=''></option>";
          foreach($item_data as $key=>$value1):
            $dy_code=$dy_code."'<option  value='$value1->item_id' ($value1->item_id == $value1->item_id ? 
             selected ='selected' >$value1->item_id-$value->item_id</option>";
          endforeach;
      }
      echo $dy_code;?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `if-statement` and add selected as `variable` in `php`

```
 <table class="table" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th> <button type="button" id="add_new_row" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $dy_code     = "";
    $selectedVal = null;
    foreach ($edit_item_data as $key => $value) {
        $dy_code = $dy_code . "<select class='select2_single form-control chosen-select item_id item_select'`enter code here`
    tabindex='-1' name='item_data[]'>";
        $dy_code = $dy_code . "<option value=''></option>";
        foreach ($item_data as $key => $value1):
            if ($value1->item_id == $value1->item_id) {
                $selectedVal = "selected";
            } else {
                $selectedVal = null;
            }
            $dy_code = $dy_code . "'<option  value='$value1->item_id' " . $selectedVal . " >$value1->item_id-$value->item_id</option>";
        endforeach;
    }
    echo $dy_code;
    ?>
    </table>
```